# How to create a one to many relationship using SQL Server 2008 in Diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use Microsoft Sql Server 2008 and create my data base in the diagram, this is the example:
[image]

this corresponds to the following example:

Using a banking example, say we have a customer master record along with any number of 
associated transaction records. The number of these transaction records could range from none, which corresponds to when a customer is new to the bank and hasn’t made a deposit or performed a transaction, to one or more, which corresponds to when there has been an initial deposit in an account, and then further deposits or withdrawal transactions after that

but I've tried setting relationship among two tables of one to many in the diagram and I only get a relationship one-to-one, Moreover I have tried to generate code diagram and I could not

Comment: A one to many means the primary key is the foreign key in another table (which normally has its own primary key).

Comment: Hello! First of all, I suggest to not just use ID as a column name. You will be confused on joins and other occasions which ID and you always need to include the table name. Better name it e.h. pkCustomer and pkAccountTransaction. Then, also use just singular entity names (not Customers), this is quite a standard nowadays. FOr the problem: If I open Database Diagrams, add 2 tables, and then drag & drop from the master table to the detail table, I get a 1:n relation. it will specifically ask for the information who is the primary key, and who is the detail key. But then it should be ok!

Comment: I forgot: Name the foreign key fkCustomer in the detail table, so you will immediately know this is a foreign key and also from which table

Comment: As each customer can have more than one'account;. You need an account table with as least three columns. id, customer_id and account_title. Then make 'customer_id' of 'account' a 'foreign key' of 'customer'.